# Efficient count of incoming edges Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

### Goal:

Sort the vertices of a given `label` by the descending number of incoming edges of a given `type` in the most efficient way.

### Configuration:

- Ubuntu VM, 23Go RAM
- JanusGraph 0.6.1 full
- local graph (default `conf/remote.yaml` file used)
- ~400k vertices (~2k with the `label`)
- ~1.5m relationships (~1m with the `type`)
- some indexing work has been done, nothing on the relationships though

### What I am doing:

```
g.V().hasLabel(<label>).
    order().
        by(inE(<type>).count(),desc).
    limit(10).
    project("name","score").
        by(<property_name>).
        by(inE(<type>).count())
```

### Issue:

While this query gives the expected results, it is really slow (up to 7+ minutes) and this execution time is not affordable. Is there a way to improve it? Whether it is an improvement to the query itself, or adding an index somewhere that could help...

### What I have seen:

- I have looked into [composite indexes](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/#composite-index) and [mixed indexes](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/#mixed-index) and they seem to not affect my problem
- I have considered [the vertex-centric indexes](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/#edge-indexes): I think it wouldn't be useful here as I don't want a subset of the incoming edges of type `type`, but the total number of them. Would it still be a beneficial side-effect (assuming I understand them correctly) of the vertex-centric indexes?

Thanks to everyone reading/replying!

### Solutions:

- Simply changing the query to the one as rewritten in [@KelvinLawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442034/kelvin-lawrence)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72689818/16521194) makes it quite a bit faster! Without any other changes, the execution time went from 7+ minutes to ~2 minutes.
- Once the `vertex_label` property has been added and indexed on, and changing the `hasLabel(<label>)` into `has("vertex_label", <label>)`, the execution time went down again from 2 minutes to ~5 seconds. The `vertex_label` property doesn't have any other use but to enable indexing on the type of vertex, [JanusGraph not supporting indexing on labels](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/283), it provides a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that perhaps your query is doing quite a bit of repeated work there. What about something like this:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('<label>').
      group().
        by('<key>').
        by(inE('<type>').count()).
      order(local).
        by(values,desc).
      unfold().
      limit(10)
```

From memory, I don't think JanusGraph supports indexing on a label which may be part of the problem here. If so, storing the label also as a property, and creating an index on that property may help the initial finding of the 2K vertices.

**UPDATED 2022-06-21** To show an actual example.

Using the air-routes data set, the query might look like this:

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').
......1>       group().
......2>         by('code').
......3>         by(inE('route').count()).
......4>       order(local).
......5>         by(values,desc).
......6>       unfold().
......7>       limit(10)   
  
==>FRA=307
==>IST=307
==>CDG=294
==>AMS=284
==>MUC=271
==>ORD=263
==>DFW=251
==>PEK=249
==>DXB=247
==>ATL=242
```

Comment: I'll try adding the label as property and indexing on it, if JanusGraph needs to initially go through every vertex, it may be useful already. I don't understand what could be the `key` parameter you're using though.

Comment: I'll add a concrete example using the air routes data set, the `key` would just be a convenient property key to group by on each vertex,

Comment: Ok, I think I get it! I'll try this too! Wil indexation on this `key` be useful? It is already indexed but simply out of curiosity.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea of the type of performances that can be expected in this situation? Alternatively, any idea of what you'd do to improve these performances?

Comment: I don't think you should need to index on that, just the key that is a copy of the label. In the air-routes data set you may notice each vertex has a `type` property which is the same as the label. I did this specifically for this case with JanusGraph.

Comment: On performance I would have to say try it. I think it should help. Please let me know!

Comment: I have edited the post to include the times. Do you have any comments on them? Also, if I wanted to do this exact same request but instead of displaying the `code`, it would display another property (that might not be unique, hence the impossibility to do the group operation on this one), how would this be done? In short, is there a way to access the rest of the vertex's properties?